# Apply a function to all cells in Spark DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to convert some Pandas code to Spark for scaling. `myfunc` is a wrapper to a complex API that takes a string and returns a new string (meaning I can't use vectorized functions).

```
def myfunc(ds):
    for attribute, value in ds.items():
        value = api_function(attribute, value)
        ds[attribute] = value
    return ds

df = df.apply(myfunc, axis='columns')
```

`myfunc` takes a DataSeries, breaks it up into individual cells, calls the API for each cell, and builds a new DataSeries with the same column names. This effectively modifies all cells in the DataFrame.

I'm new to Spark and I want to translate this logic using `pyspark`. I've converted my pandas DataFrame to Spark:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('My app').getOrCreate()
spark_schema = StructType([StructField(c, StringType(), True) for c in df.columns])
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df, schema=spark_schema)
```

This is where I get lost. Do I need a `UDF`, a `pandas_udf`? How do I iterate across all cells and return a new string for each using `myfunc`? `spark_df.foreach()` doesn't return anything and it doesn't have a `map()` function.

I can modify `myfunc` from `DataSeries` -> `DataSeries` to `string` -> `string` if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is:

```
udf_func = udf(func, StringType())
for col_name in spark_df.columns:
    spark_df = spark_df.withColumn(col_name, udf_func(lit(col_name), col_name))
return spark_df.toPandas()
```

There are 3 key insights that helped me figure this out:

1. If you use `withColumn` with the name of an existing column (`col_name`), Spark "overwrites"/shadows the original column. This essentially gives the appearance of editing the column directly as if it were mutable.
2. By creating a loop across the original columns and reusing the same DataFrame variable `spark_df`, I use the same principle to simulate a mutable DataFrame, creating a chain of column-wise transformations, each time "overwriting" a column (per #1 - see below)
3. Spark `UDFs` expect all parameters to be `Column` types, which means it attempts to resolve column values for each parameter. Because `api_function`'s first parameter is a literal value that will be the same for all rows in the vector, you must use the `lit()` function. Simply passing col_name to the function will attempt to extract the column values for that column. As far as I could tell, passing `col_name` is equivalent to passing `col(col_name)`.

Assuming 3 columns 'a', 'b' and 'c', unrolling this concept would look like this:

```
spark_df = spark_df.withColumn('a', udf_func(lit('a'), 'a')
                   .withColumn('b', udf_func(lit('b'), 'b')
                   .withColumn('c', udf_func(lit('c'), 'c')
```

Answer (score 7):

## Option 1: Use a UDF on One Column at a Time

The simplest approach would be to rewrite your function to take a string as an argument (so that it is `string` -> `string`) and use a UDF.  There's a nice example [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html). This works on one column at a time.  So, if your `DataFrame` has a reasonable number of columns, you can apply the UDF to each column one at a time:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
new_df = df.select(udf(col("col1")), udf(col("col2")), ...)
```

### Example

```
df = sc.parallelize([[1, 4], [2,5], [3,6]]).toDF(["col1", "col2"])
df.show()
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1|   4|
|   2|   5|
|   3|   6|
+----+----+

def plus1_udf(x):
    return x + 1
plus1 = spark.udf.register("plus1", plus1_udf)

new_df = df.select(plus1(col("col1")), plus1(col("col2")))
new_df.show()
+-----------+-----------+
|plus1(col1)|plus1(col2)|
+-----------+-----------+
|          2|          5|
|          3|          6|
|          4|          7|
+-----------+-----------+
```

## Option 2: Map the entire DataFrame at once

`map` is available for Scala `DataFrame`s, but, at the moment, not in PySpark.
The lower-level [RDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD) API does have a `map` function in PySpark.  So, if you have too many columns to transform one at a time, you could operate on every single cell in the `DataFrame` like this:

```
def map_fn(row):
    return [api_function(x) for (column, x) in row.asDict().items()

column_names = df.columns
new_df = df.rdd.map(map_fn).toDF(df.columns)
```

### Example

```
df = sc.parallelize([[1, 4], [2,5], [3,6]]).toDF(["col1", "col2"])
def map_fn(row):
   return [value + 1 for (_, value) in row.asDict().items()]

columns = df.columns
new_df = df.rdd.map(map_fn).toDF(columns)
new_df.show()
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   2|   5|
|   3|   6|
|   4|   7|
+----+----+
```

## Context

The [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreach) of `foreach` only gives the example of printing, but we can verify looking at the [code](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.foreach) that it indeed does not return anything.

You can read about `pandas_udf` in [this post](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html), but it seems that it is most suited to vectorized functions, which, as you pointed out, you can't use because of `api_function`.

Comment: The UDF example follows the usual path of adding its output as a new column. How would I apply it to all existing cells?

Comment: @Steven - Thanks for the comment.  I expanded my answer a bit to more specifically address your question.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, I'm still battling Spark on some fronts so I can make sense of it all.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. What I was missing was the insights I describe in my answer, specifically the ability to shadow existing columns using `withColumn`. Option 1 was heading in the right direction, but the shadowing of columns and assigning a chain of column-wise transformations back to the original variable in each iteration is what gave me the complete solution of editing a seemingly mutable DataFrame in place, just like `df = df.apply()` does in Pandas. Thanks again.